# in javascript whay use " var that = this "

Tags: javascript

hi i am new with javascript

What is the benefit of using this line

`var that = this`

An example

```
function Person( firstname, lastname, age ) {

this.firstname = firstname;

this.lastname = lastname;

this.age = age;

getfullname = function() {

return firstname + “ “ + lastname; }

var that = this;

this.sayHi = function() {

document.write( “Hi my name is “ + getfullname() + “ and I am “ + that.age + “years old.”);

} }
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [in javascript why use " var that = this "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355041/in-javascript-why-use-var-that-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is context sensitive. Using `that` makes sure that when `sayHi` is called it can use the `this` value from when `getfullname` was called.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it's to fix the meaning of *this* to what it refers to at the time *that* is assigned.  it wouldn't make any difference in your example, but it can do when a function is called from a different context.

In Javascript *this* is a rather fluid concept. It is **not** the same as *this* in OO languages like c#.