# in javascript why use " var that = this "

Tags: javascript

hi i am new with javascript

What is the benefit of using this line

`var that = this`

An example

```
function Person( firstname, lastname, age ) {

    this.firstname = firstname;

    this.lastname = lastname;

    this.age = age;

    getfullname = function() {

        return firstname + “ “ + lastname;
    };

    var that = this;


    this.sayHi = function() {

        document.write( “Hi my name is “ + getfullname() + “ and I am “ + that.age + “years old.”);

    };
}
```

thanks

Comment: Hi tarek11011, this is a question better suited for StackOverflow. In fact, the question is [already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript) a few times there

Comment: That question is about the use of var which isn't what is being asked here

Comment: why does `getfullname` not have a `this` before it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

because in the inner function *this* will not be the same object as in the outer, so by aliasing it to *that* you can make sure you are talking to the same object.